# "cannot import name" error in geovoronoi.plotting, related to geopandas

Tags: python, installation, python-import, geopandas

I am trying to use the python package [geovoronoi](https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/geovoronoi) to make a visualization.

I imported a few standard packages and a few functions from geovoronoi.plotting, per the github instructions.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import contextily as ctx
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union, unary_union
from geovoronoi import coords_to_points, voronoi_regions_from_coords
from geovoronoi.plotting import subplot_for_map, plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area
```

However I get the following error about the `_flatten_multi_geoms` function in `geopandas`, nested within `geovoronoi.plotting`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/fv/29w2936j23d9dy29dybwh7680000gn/T/ipykernel_11149/4101024432.py in <module>
      4 from shapely.ops import cascaded_union, unary_union
      5 from geovoronoi import coords_to_points, voronoi_regions_from_coords
----> 6 from geovoronoi.plotting import subplot_for_map, plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geovoronoi/plotting.py in <module>
      9 from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
     10 from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch
---> 11 from geopandas.plotting import _flatten_multi_geoms
     12 from geopandas import GeoSeries
     13 

ImportError: cannot import name '_flatten_multi_geoms' from 'geopandas.plotting'
```

How can I resolve this issue with the underlying function? Here's the [source code](https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/geovoronoi/blob/master/geovoronoi/plotting.py) from geovoronoi.plotting. Am I making a circular dependency because I already imported geopandas in the first line? Is there an issue because the function begins with a "__"? Any help is appreciated.

I tried uninstalling both geopandas and geovoronoi.plotting, then installing just one, and running the same code block. Then vice versa with just the one package installed. I expected uninstalling geopandas, and just running geovoronoi.plotting would isolate the circular-dependency issue. Both resulted in the same error message, so it's probably something else (?).

Answer (score 0):

GeoVoronoi apparently imported a private `_flatten_multi_geoms` function from geopandas. That function has likely changed and is not available anymore. You will need to use older GeoPandas to make this work. GeoPandas 0.12 should work.